# WPF multiple backgroundworkers completed

Tags: wpf

I have 4 backgroundworkers running on my WPF application. I need to perform an action when all of them have completed. How can I coordinate their completion?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be tracking each of those completion in a static variable as increment of count or something. If your case is more complex, please give further details.